# Undefined message variable NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have been following this tutorial for my node app to implement authentication: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

The issue I am having is I'm getting this error when running the app: (my code is exacltly how it should be according to the above website).

[image]

I tried searching for an answer but the best I could get is adding this function to my server code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.message = req.flash();
    next();
});
```

This loads the application without any errors however, the message does not seem to be displayed in my front-end. Not exactly sure why but Im getting this problem with this project only, I can implement messages without any issues in my other projects.

I've added my github link below but heres bits of my code:

**routes.js**

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect : '/#contact',
    failureFlash : true
}));
```

**passport.js**

```
if (user) {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Email already in use!'));
}
```

**index.ejs**

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

Github project: https://github.coventry.ac.uk/salmanfazal01/304CEM-Back-End

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error i think you didn't pass the variable `message` correctly to the `ejs` view.

So you have 2 solutions

1- In your `routes.js` file you need to pass message while rendering `index` view, this is how the example you are following is done.

So Change

```
//GET homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

To

```
//GET homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index' , {message: <your data> });
});
```

---

2- using `res.locals` and `res.flash` which is the solution you found, but you are not actually passing any values in `req.flash()`

So replace this code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.message = req.flash();
    next();
});
```

with

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    req.flash("info" , "first message"); //here you add message under type info
    req.flash("info" , "second message"); // here you add another message under type info

    next();
});
```

and in your `route.js`

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index' , {message : req.flash("info")}); //set message from req.flash type info
    });

    //or

   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.locals.message = req.flash("info"); //set locals.message from req.flash type info 
        res.render('index');
    });
```

Comment: You're a legend mate! I spent the last couple of hours trying to fix it and it turned out to be something so minor :/
Tried your first solution and it worked. Basically, my sign up/in forms are within my index page and I was rendering them separately and passing the message within them instead of the main hompage. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it helped :)